# Dagger. Внедрение зависимости в ViewModel

Tags: android, di, dagger

Компонент для всего приложения App создается так:

```
appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
```

Компонент для BaseActivity создается через dependencies от AppComponent:

```
activityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
                .appComponent(((App)getApplication()).getComponent())
                .build();
```

Компонент для BaseFragment создается через dependencies от ActivityComponent:

```
fragmentComponent = DaggerFragmentComponent.builder()
                .fragmentModule(new FragmentModule(this))
                .activityComponent(((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getActivityComponent())
                .build();
```

Я использую модель MVVM, и мне нужна зависимость от AppComponent для BaseViewModel. Как правильно получить экземпляр AppComponent, созданного в Application?

```
viewModelComponent = DaggerViewModelComponent.builder()
                    .appComponent(??? как его получить ???)
                    .build();
```

Можно в Application создать `public static AppComponent getAppComponent(){return appComponent;}`, нормальный ли это подход?

Comment: зачем вам компонента под вью модель? делаете что-то странное

Comment: @SviatVolkov Отправлять запрос. Или в Presenter получить компоненту вместо ViewModel, не суть. Вопрос в архитектуре: в AppComponent методы для HTTP-запроса, доступ к этому компоненту естественным образом получается из активностей и фрагментов. Но как быть с обособленными частями приложения, если тоже нужен доступ к этому компоненту, чтобы выполнить HTTP-запрос?

Comment: вы хотите во ViewModel засунуть апи клиент, который вы будете вызывать из вью модели?

Comment: @SviatVolkov при создании фрагмента должны загружаться некоторые данные с сервера. Это запрос лучше делать во ViewModel, а не в Fragment классе (который является частью View в MVVM), наверное.

Comment: окей, чуть позже распишу как правильно связать ViewModel Dagger Fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделаем маленький пример для вашей задачи: "Сделать запрос не сервер из вью модели, и чтоб всё это работало через даггер"

Первое: у нас есть `AppComponent` у которого есть `AppModule` в котором лежит ваша зависимость с классом обращения к серверу. Назовём эту зависимость `ServiceApi`

(Пишу на Котлине т.к. мне так привычнее, извиняюсь заранее, если совсем не понятно, позднее перепишу на джаву **ВАЖНО: всё писал от руки по памяти**)

```
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
  fun provideServiceApi() : ServiceApi
}

@Module
abstract class AppModule {

    @Module
    companion object {

     @JvmStatic
     @Provides
     fun provideServiceApi() {
             return ServiceApi()
     }
    }
}
```

Движемся в сторону Активити (Фрагмент я трогать не буду, т.к. там всё аналогично активити):

```
@Component(dependecies = AppComponent::class, modules = [MyActivityModule::class])
@ActivityScope
interface ActivityComponent() {
   fun inject(activity: MyActivity)
}
```

Далее наступает вопрос. как создать фабрику для вью моделей? Если вашей ViewModel нужны параметры из активити, то тогда ваша фабрика должна быть в скоупе активити и лежать в даггер модуле активити (для фрагмента всё аналогично)

Т.е. в таком случае, мы инжектим параметры в `ViewModelFactory` а саму `ViewModel` создаём обычным путём

```
class MyViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val depFromActivity: Object, private val serviceApi: ServiceApi): ViewModelProvider.Factory {

  override fun create(): ViewModel {
      return MyViewModel(depFromActivity, serviceApi)
  }
}

@Module
interface MyActivityModule(private val activity: MyActivity) {
   @Binds
   @ActivityScope
   fun bindViewModelFactory(impl: MyViewModelFactory) : ViewModelProvider.Factory

   @Provides
   @ActivityScope
   fun provideScopedDependency(): Object {
     return activity.getObject()
   }
}
```

Как это работает: Чтобы заинжектить в фабрику зависимость, конструктору надо добавить аннотацию `@Inject`, а `ApiService` даггер нам даст из `AppComponent` т.к. мы в зависимостях у `ActivityComponent` указали откуда возьмем `ApiService`

Этап построения графа окончен. Теперь как всё это заинитить и заинжектить?

Сначала инитим `AppComponent`

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    private val appComponent by lazy { DaggerAppComponent.builder().build() }

    fun getAppComponent(): {
      return  appComponent
    }
}


class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

     @Inject
     lateinit var factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

     lateinit var viewMode: MyViewModel

     override fun onCreate(...) {
      DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
    .appComponent((applicatios as MyApplication).getAppComponent())
    .activityModule(ActivityModule(this))
    .build() //создали компоненту
    .inject(this) // проинитили фабрику через даггер

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(MyViewModel::class)

}
```

Если вашей `ViewModel` не нужны зависимости из активити/фрагмента то можно сделать очень красиво: Одна фабрика на множество вью моделей. Подробнее об этом можете почитать в [статье (англ)](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/understanding-dagger-2-multibindings-viewmodel-8418eb372848)